# Can't mount xfs filesystem after reboot

Tags: mount, aws, xfs

I have an amazon ec2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04. It has an attached EBS volume formatted as XFS.  It's worked fine for a long time.  However, after a reboot today, the volume is no longer being mounted.

If I try to mount it manually with:

```
mount -t auto /dev/xvdf /usr/local/mnt/media
```

I get

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'xfs'
```

So, it seems I'm now unable to mount this volume.  Strangely if I check /dev/xvdf, it is indeed an xfs filesytem.

```
file -s /dev/xvdf
/dev/xvdf: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 256, v2 dirs)
```

So apparently ubuntu "forgot" about XFS.

Any help or input would be really appreciated as I'm stumped.

**Edit**

Output of

```
lsmod | grep xfs
```

returns nothing, and the output of

```
grep -H XFS_FS /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

returns

```
grep: /boot/config-3.2.0-64-virtual: No such file or directory
```

So now I'm really confused, xfs has apparently disappeared from this server.

**Edit**

I can't load the module manually either

```
modprobe -v xfs

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.2.0-64-virtual/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the outputs of `lsmod | grep xfs` and `grep -H XFS_FS /boot/config-$(uname -r)` please? That will give us somewhere to start looking.

Comment: Hmm so it looks like the ec2 kernels are configured a bit differently - I don't think I'll be much help here, sorry.

Comment: I presume you've tried manually inserting the kernel module and noting any error messages? `sudo modprobe -v xfs`

Comment: Yes, tried and it will not load the module. Updated the question